# Add a day to a datetime project parameter and store in a variable of type datetime in using SSIS expression

Tags: datetime, variables, ssis, expression, dateadd

I am trying to add a day to a project parameter of type DATETIME and store the results in a  variable in SSIS which of type DATETIME.

I am using this below expression in variable

```
dateadd(day,1,(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE) @[$Project::Start_Date])
```

and getting this below error

> ### TITLE: Expression Builder
>
> Expression cannot be evaluated.
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE%202015&ProdVer=14.0.23107.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.TaskUIFramework.TaskUIFrameworkSR&EvtID=FailToEvaluateExpression&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The expression contains unrecognized token "day". If "day" is a
> variable, it should be expressed as "@day". The specified token is not
> valid. If the token is intended to be a variable name, it should be
> prefixed with the @ symbol.
>
> Attempt to parse the expression "dateadd(day,1,(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)
> @[$Project::Start_Date])" failed and returned error code 0xC00470A4.
> The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or
> it might not be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.
>
> (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls)
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Can anyone help me to resolve the above problem.

Comment: what is the value of @[$Project::Start_Date]? It literally says that value cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

The argument to the first parameter for dateadd is a string, not a constant/enumeration so it should be

```
dateadd("day",1,(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE) @[$Project::Start_Date])
```

### The long way around

I assume the desire is to get the next day's date with the supplied expression

```
dateadd(day,1,(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE) @[$Project::Start_Date])
```

When I run into issues with expressions, I break them down into the most atomic statement and then compose from there.

I'm using a SSIS scoped variable instead of a project parameter but the logic will hold true.

I have an SSIS variable, Start_Date of data type DateTime with an initial value of `2022-06-01 09:22 AM` (convert that to your current locale's preference for date presenation)

I created a new variable, `Start_DateOnly` and used the following expression

```
(DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)  @[User::Start_Date]
```

Great, that shows 2022-06-01 (no time component in the Variables window although if you evaluate in the Expression editor, it will show midnight). And the explainer - we convert to the DT_DBDATE datatype to drop the time component but DT_DBDATE is incompatible with the displayed DateTime data type so we explicitly convert to DT_DATE.

Cool beans, now all we need to do is confirm the dateadd function works as expected with our new variable

```
dateadd(day, 1, @[User::Start_DateOnly])
```

What the heck?

> Expression cannot be evaluated.

> The expression contains unrecognized token "day". If "day" is a variable, it should be expressed as "@day". The specified token is not valid. If the token is intended to be a variable name, it should be prefixed with the @ symbol.

Oh... yeah, while this language is similar to TSQL, the datepart parameter is a  string, not an enum/constant so the syntax should be

```
dateadd("day", 1, @[User::Start_DateOnly])
```

Yup, that evaluates to `2022-06-02 12:00 AM`